# SQL Server performance very very LOW in UPDATE/INSERT operations (but not always)

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-update

I have a very simple database with this table

This table is used to generate counters for some operations (Order N°, Invoice Num ecc.)

The problem is that on my developer machine the generation of 1000 counters needs 0.3s instead on a Virtual machine with SQL Server on Windows Azure needs 8 seconds more than 20 times slower.

The script I used is this:

```
    SET STATISTICS IO ON; 
    SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

    CREATE DATABASE mytest;
    GO

    USE mytest;

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Counters]
    (
        [SequenceName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
        [LastUsed] [bigint] NULL,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_Counters] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([SequenceName] ASC)
      WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
      GO

        Declare @counter int
        declare @LastUsed as BIGINT
        declare @SequenceName as varchar(100)

        Set @counter = 1

        set @SequenceName = 'AA00TEST-DELETE-THIS'

        set Nocount  on;

        DELETE FROM Counters

        INSERT INTO [dbo].[Counters] ([SequenceName] ,[LastUsed]) VALUES ('AA00TEST-DELETE-THIS', 0)


        While @counter <= 1000
        Begin

             UPDATE Counters
                     SET LastUsed = LastUsed + 1,
                            @LastUsed = LastUsed + 1
                     WHERE SequenceName=@SequenceName

            Set @counter = @counter + 1

        End

        SELECT LastUsed From Counters WHERE SequenceName=@SequenceName

DROP TABLE Counters
GO

USE master
GO

DROP DATABASE mytest
GO
```

Note tha if I replace the UPDATE istruction with this one the execution time is 0.3s:

```
SELECT @LastUsed = LastUsed + 1 FROM Counters WHERE SequenceName=@SequenceName
```

Note that I test this behaviour on many servers and in all I got the same performance.

I test on Azure VM SQL Server with 8 CPU, SQL 2014... 8 Sec.

I test on Azure DB... 8 Sec.

I test on a VMWare virtual machine, SQL 2005 8 sec.

I test on a phisical SQL Server server with 16 CPU, SQL 2008... 8 Sec.

On my MacBook pro with Windows 8 Pro SQL 2012... 0,3sec
On my PC with Windows 8 Pro SQL 2012... 0,3sec

The script is executed directly on the server with Managemant Studio connected to localhost. No network roundtrip is present and no application present, I'm directly on the server and on SQL Server core.

This are statistics on my PC (1 iteration):

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 2 ms.
Table 'Counters'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Counters'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

This are statistics on Server (1 iteration):

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 11 ms.
Table 'Counters'. Scan count 0, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 18 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
Table 'Counters'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 8 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 0 ms.
```

All PC And server have the same "Recovery model"

I have found no way to boost it up

Thank You!

Comment: Why, oh why, would you use such a "counter" table?

Comment: I need a language/platform/enviroment/framework independent way to generate human readable Tables ID/Key unique identifiers. Or Order Numbers or Invoice Numbers.

Comment: There are very good use cases for using this pattern.

Comment: The problem is not the "pattern", the problem is the performance difference between Developer environment and server evnvironment in more then 20 times slower that I do not undestand.

Comment: Can you post an execution plan and `SET STATISTICS IO ON; SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` for versions of the test with a `SELECT` and an `UPDATE`? You're right in that it doesn't seem to be a regular network roundtrip time if a `SELECT` runs fine for you. Can you also replace `DELETE FROM` with a `TRUNCATE TABLE` to be sure all tested instances begin from the same state? Also, are you sure database settings for all tested instances are the same, e.g. log file size, log file autogrowth settings, recovery mode, compatibility mode.

Comment: I've changed the post including the information you request. I modified the script to simplify the test for every soul that want to test it on his PC or on his server and tell me if a normal behaviour or I made som errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try many many configurations and settings on azure disks and blobs.
Finally I found the problem!

**The problem is the OBSCENE performance of Windows Azure Disks in Write.**

Creating the database on the Temporary Disk of the Azure Server where the virtual machine is hosted the time for execution go to 0sec.

```
CREATE DATABASE [mytest] ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'mytest_Data', FILENAME = N'D:\Test\mytest_Data.mdf')
    LOG ON 
( NAME = N'mytest_Log', FILENAME = N'D:\Test\mytest_Log.ldf')
GO
```

Finally there are NO Solution.

I try to use SQL Azure but the performance in UPDATE or INSERT are similar to the SQL Inside the virtual machine. Little bit better.